# No grub entry for Windows 7 after installing maverick

Tags: 10.10, grub2

A friend of mine had Windows 7 and Windows XP running in his Sony Vaio. I replaced Windows XP with Ubuntu 10.10. After that the laptop directly boots into Ubuntu. Even the grub menu does not appear during startup. I tried `sudo update-grub`, `sudo update-burg` but windows was not recognized.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To restore the Windows 7 bootloader, you must first boot off your 7 installation DVD.
- When you get to the Regional settings, select your Location/Keyboard setting then click next. On the next page you must click on **Repair your computer**.
- On the next page, if it finds your Windows Vista/7 installation, make sure it is UNSELECTED before clicking next.Then click on **Command prompt**.
- From there, type in the folowing,

  `bootrec.exe /fixboot`

  `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`
- Now close the two windows and click **Restart**.

**Note:**

- If it din help you,post the results of http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the following [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999). Hope the 4 & 5 steps can help you.

This is also a very helpful [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

I think the same problem is being discussed in the following [thread](http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634127)
The guy who posted seemed to have got the same problem and has rectified it.

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: I actually don't want to reinstall windows...it takes lot of time to install additional software...

Comment: @chethan: If Windows does not appear in the boot menu, I think you will need to edit /boot/grub/menu.lst.. Please try that..

Comment: <http://superuser.com/questions/112678/how-do-i-make-grub2-appear-after-installing-ubuntu-on-a-drive-with-windows-7-no> Another link where a similar problem is being discussed

Comment: Actually the guide will work only for grub versions < 2.0. From karmic onwards, grub 2.0 is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your grub configuration to see whether the timeout option has been disabled or something.

For old grub versions, see [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-the-grub-menu-timeout-on-ubuntu/).
For newer versions, see [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316893).